# WPF DocumentViewer throw exception during scrolling

Tags: c#, wpf, xps, documentviewer, gembox-spreadsheet

I've the problem, that the WPF-DocumentViewer throws exceptions during scrolling
through the document. The document it self was loaded successful and is shown correctly.

I get the following error message: `Unkown URI-Prefix`.

The XPS is generated by GemBox.Spreadsheet like: [Export to XpsDocument / DocumentViewer Control](http://www.gemboxsoftware.com/SampleExplorer/Spreadsheet/WPF/ExporttoXpsDocument_DocumentViewerControl?tab=cs)

I don't get why the xps it loaded and an exception is thrown.

Thank you!

Comment: It renders on demand.  I suspect it is coming across some bad syntax.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa384461(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: @Blam thank you, so i can't do anything, becuase it is a third party component?

Comment: I would not give up.  You may just need to add a reference.  It was just a comment.  That is where I would start.

Answer (score 1):

This problem occurred because the XpsDocument object needs to stay referenced so that DocumentViewer can access additional required resources (notice the use of `XpsDocument xpsDocument;` in that sample code).
Otherwise GC will collect the XpsDocument object and DocumentViewer will not be able to work.

Just as an FYI, you can also find this information in [DocumentViewer.Document property's documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.documents.idocumentpaginatorsource(v=vs.110).aspx) (see the example code and comments which are provided).